# ¿Cómo hago para que una celda cambie su color dependiendo del valor de esta jinja2?

Tags: mysql, python, html5, flask

Guardé los datos de una consulta en la variable facturas. Esta es una tupla, la cual me sirve para llenar la tabla con los datos, en la última celda guardo el valor del estado de la factura que quiero cambiar de color dependiendo del estado en que se encuentre.

Intenté poniendo una condicional adentro del ciclo `for` pero me cambia todo de un mismo color.

1 = pendiente
2 = entregado

[image: Imagen del html]`

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="card text-black bg-primary mb-3" style="max-width: 100rem;">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-dark">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Factura</th>
                    <th>Fecha</th>
                    <th>Observaciones</th>
                    <th>Piezas</th>
                    <th>Clave del producto</th>
                    <th>Descripcion</th>
                    <th>Unidad de medida</th>
                    <th>Estado</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for factura in facturas %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ factura.0 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ factura.1 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ factura.2 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ factura.3 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ factura.4 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ factura.5 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ factura.6 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ factura.7 }}</td>

                {% if factura.8 == 1 %}
                <td class="bg-warning">{{ factura.8 }}</td>
                {% else %}
                <td class="bg-success">{{ factura.8 }}</td>

                {% endif %}
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Creo que `factura.8` no te está devolviendo un número sino un texto, por lo que la condición debe estar comparando el texto **'pendiente'**, algo así: `{% if factura.8 == 'pendiente' %}`...

Comment: Excelente mi pana, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, ya pude arreglar ese error

Answer (score 0):

El codigo en jinja y html quedaría de esta forma

```
        <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="card text-black bg-primary mb-3" style="max-width: 95rem;">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-light">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Factura</th>
                        <th>Fecha</th>
                        <th>Observaciones</th>
                        <th>Piezas</th>
                        <th>Clave del producto</th>
                        <th>Descripcion</th>
                        <th>Unidad de medida</th>
                        <th>Estado</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for factura in facturas %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ factura.0 }}</td>
                        <td>{{ factura.1 }}</td>
                        <td>{{ factura.2 }}</td>
                        <td>{{ factura.3 }}</td>
                        <td>{{ factura.4 }}</td>
                        <td>{{ factura.5 }}</td>
                        <td>{{ factura.6 }}</td>
                        <td>{{ factura.7 }}</td>
                        {% if factura.8 == 'Pendiente' %}
                        <td class="bg-warning">{{ factura.8 }}</td>
                        {% elif factura.8 == 'Entregado' %}
                        <td class="bg-success">{{ factura.8 }}</td>
                        {% else %}
                        <td class="bg-danger">{{ factura.8 }}</td>
                        {% endif %}
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]